# iPad\iPhone application structure

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, itunes, universal

I am going to build an iOS application that will have different iPad\iPhone views, but will share some business logic. I want to develop the application in different XCode projects, not in a universal mode (as this will require less development and testing).

I understood from the 'iPad Programming Guide', that "Creating a universal application allows you to sell one application that supports all device types".

I would like to allow this behavior, but still develop on two different XCode projects (iPad and iPhone). Is there a way to do so? Maybe using the same application id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Do not split* the app into separate iPhone and iPad apps, *unless* you are adding some **significant functionality** to the iPad app to warrant it as a completely separate app.

I say this because I just did this - (I had an existing app, and release a separate iPad version of it.) Apple *rejected* the application for this reason.

See Apple's guidlines: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

There is also info on creating universal apps here:

http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/resources/introductiontouniversalapps.pdf

Comment: Thanks Brad! That what I was looking, a good reason for not doing so.

Comment: BTW - the only reason I wanted to split it into two different apps was so I could build my iPhone version for iOS 4 - and have Fast-App-Switching support in it. (If I did a "universal" app, it would have to be built for iOS 3.2, and I'd have no FAS.) Now that the SDK for 4.2 is out - this would no longer be an issue - (as long as your client's iPads are upgraded to 4.2.)

Answer (score 0):

You can just develop one app specifically for the iPad, and one specifically for the iPhone/iPod Touch. Many apps do this, including Things and Things for iPad. Creating two separate apps could increase your revenue, as well, since some people have both devices; if they really like your app, they will purchase it twice.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against splitting the projects... That's because when you develop a universal application, it comes as one `myApp.app` bundle that gets loaded on the phone.  It's actually rather trivial to code for the different platforms, and just a matter of screen resolution changes/a different nib.  Basic logic and underlying code should remain the same.

[Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1111/how-to-port-an-iphone-application-to-the-ipad) has posted a great tutorial on how to do this.

Comment: If I will not find any solution I will fall back to that, for sure. Great tutorial indeed!